# How select multiple ex wild card tables in Clickhouse?

Tags: google-bigquery, clickhouse

I used to use google bigquery and selected multiple wild card tables with query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM  project.dataset.events_* 
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20220704" AND "20220731"
```

and it selects all tables between this two dates

Is it possible in Clickhouse to query multiple tables with _TABLE_SUFFIX or analog if i only have bunch of tables like

```
1. events_20210501
2. events_20210502
3. events_20210503
...
```

with table engine `ReplicatedMergeTree`?
Is it possible to create wild card analog in clickhouse?

Answer (score 2):

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/special/merge

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/table-functions/merge

```sql
create table A1 Engine=Memory as select 1 a;
create table A2 Engine=Memory as select 2 a;

select * from merge(currentDatabase(), '^A.$');
┌─a─┐
│ 1 │
└───┘
┌─a─┐
│ 2 │
└───┘

select * from merge(currentDatabase(), 'A');
┌─a─┐
│ 1 │
└───┘
┌─a─┐
│ 2 │
└───┘
```